# Flow_from_directory() won't load any image

Tags: python, keras, data-augmentation

i'm trying to load images for training a CNN using keras flow_from_directorY(), but seems that is having hard times finding the images. i'm running the code on google colab

```
!unzip "/content/drive/My Drive/fruits.zip" -d "/content/drive/My Drive"
```

I used this command to unzip my dataset and then if i try to visualize how many images i have for every folder, it seems that it recognises the images

```
for folder in os.listdir(os.path.join(path,'training')):
folder_count = len(os.listdir(os.path.join(path,'training',folder)))
image_count.append(folder_count)
class_names.append(folder)
print('{:20s}'.format(folder), end='')
print(folder_count)
print('-'*24)
print('Number of Classes:', len(class_names))
print('Average number of images per Class: ', 
np.array(image_count).mean())
```

however, if i try to use flow_from_directory with those paths, i got that it has found 0 images

```
train_batches = train_datagenerator.flow_from_directory('/content/drive/My 
Drive/fruits-360_dataset/data/training', target_size=(224, 224), 
color_mode="rgb", classes="categorical" ,  batch_size=32, subset='training')
val_batches = train_datagenerator.flow_from_directory('/content/drive/My 
Drive/fruits-360_dataset/data/training', target_size=(224, 224), 
color_mode="rgb", classes="categorical" ,  batch_size=32, 
subset='validation')
test_batches = test_datagenerator.flow_from_directory('/content/drive/My 
Drive/fruits-360_dataset/data/test', target_size=(224, 224), 
color_mode="rgb", classes="categorical" ,  batch_size=32, shuffle=False)

Found 0 images belonging to 11 classes.
Found 0 images belonging to 11 classes.
Found 0 images belonging to 11 classes.
```

if someone could help would be really appreciated! :)